# Browser-compatible carousel

Tags: carousel

I'm new to web design and learned the basics of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and am creating a blog website.

I'm using Bootstrap to format my page and want to add a carousel, however, the Bootstrap carousel isn't compatible with some IE browsers.

Given that broad compatibility is my goal, how should I add a carousel to my website? CSS? JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap exclusively uses CSS3 for its animations, but Internet Explorer 8 & 9 don't support the necessary CSS properties. Thus, there are no slide transition animations when using these browsers. We have intentionally decided not to include jQuery-based fallbacks for the transitions.

So, if you're familiar with jquery, you can add fallback.
https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/6155151
 Otherwise, you can use any other carousels such as which is responsive which has lot of customization options, or http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified etc which are working fine even in ie7 also.

Comment: Thank you for the response! can i copy the jquery fallback straight into my .js file? or do i have to add some code into my html aswell for it to work?

Comment: you just save that file externally and include it in your slider page. if you are getting any confusion then just go with that link and read below comments on that page. or if you are not getting anything better you go with bxslider.